# listener port and serving port in server

Tags: java, serversocket, httpserver

I am planing to write one customized `http` server in java. I thought of using one listener port which will always listen for incoming calls. Whenever incoming call will come, it will accept and pass the socket object in another thread. So that thread will be responsible for serving response. When response is completed, it will be closed. But now the problem I think is that if too much request comes at a time then no more port would be available. So I am thinking of having some fixed number of serving port and reuse those for sending response back. Can anyone suggest how can i do that in java?

Comment: Are you closing the sockets connections? Port is unsigned short, so you have 65536 ports. Of course the ports it will use will be in the higher ones, but anyway you need a lots of requests per second to overcome the port's available. Its more than you overcome some system resource, like maximum TCP/IP open connections, connections in CLOSE_WAIT or TIME_WAIT state (that can take 4 minutes to return to reuse if you do not change this on system), etc

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to limit ports as much as you want to limit threads, that's why many servers use a `threadpool` that contains way less threads than the amount of available ports.